# Electronic Device Information - Where to access Laptop/TV/Camera data?

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, information-retrieval

I am hoping to build a consumer electronic device recommendation engine, similar to Decide.com among others.

After extensively searching the web, I cannot find any public API/Webservice/Database that could provide me (at least a segment of) this needed data.

Are there any sources of this information that I could use?  Free would obviously be optimal.  I do not mind having to access multiple sources and cross-referencing the data.

For example, were does Decide.com get its data?  For example, for some of its products (http://www.decide.com/p/sony-vaio-vpc-z216gx-l-laptops-28056580) there are over 35 different specifications - how?

Comment: Is the only option manual data entry?

Comment: Where do you think these sites get their data? They either create the data themselves, or buy it from someone who creates it. You're free to do the same.